# Oracle XML - adding extra text to Tag name

Tags: xml, oracle

I am developing Oracle SQL code (Oracle v9.2) to achieve the following output

```
<AvailabilityConfirmation actionCode="01" descriptionListCompleteTransmissionIndicator="true" detailListCompleteTransmissionIndicator="true">
    <ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>013</ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>
</AvailabilityConfirmation>
```

This is my SQL so far...

```
SELECT 
XMLELEMENT("AvailabilityConfirmation",
           XMLELEMENT("ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID",a.ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID)
           ) 
   AS new_inv_part
FROM (SELECT
      '013'      AS ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID
      FROM DUAL
     ) a
```

The above SQL statement produces the below output

```
 <AvailabilityConfirmation>
  <ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>013</ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>
</AvailabilityConfirmation>
```

BUT how do I get the first line to have extra text after the tag name?:

This:

```
 <AvailabilityConfirmation>
```

needs to be:

```
 <AvailabilityConfirmation actionCode="01" descriptionListCompleteTransmissionIndicator="true" detailListCompleteTransmissionIndicator="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this might help

```
XMLELEMENT("ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID", XMLATTRIBUTES(a.ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID,
   (SELECT d.actionCode FROM sometable d
   WHERE a.id = e.id) as "actionCode")
)
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLATTRIBUTES`:

```sql
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
         "AvailabilityConfirmation",
         XMLATTRIBUTES(
           '013' AS "actionCode",
           'true' AS "descriptionListCompleteTransmissionIndicator",
           'true' AS "detailListCompleteTransmissionIndicator"
         ),
         XMLELEMENT("ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID",'013')
       ) AS value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <AvailabilityConfirmation actionCode="013" descriptionListCompleteTransmissionIndicator="true" detailListCompleteTransmissionIndicator="true"><ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID>013</ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID></AvailabilityConfirmation> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a25f6ca935bf0c20f653dfe2e263c666)*